# Is there a way to disable command 'keys *' in Redis?

Tags: redis, redis-cli, elastic-cache

I'm using AWS elastic cache Redis.

I saw that `Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care` in Redis Documentation.

If I want to disable the 'key' command, Is there a way to disable command 'keys' or 'keys *' in Redis ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution

You can disable the 'keys' command using the rename-commands in the parameter group(AWS elastic cache Parameter group).